# PHP Why is my while loop not assigning each row an individual ID from column in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

Im having an issue where i can't seem to assign an ID from a column in the database to each DIV respectively.

**The Scenario:** I have a page full of clients and next to each one is a vote up and vote down button. When i click one of them it simply adds +1 to either the positive or negative column.

**What is the Issue?** The issue is no matter which client i vote for it only updates the ClientID '1'

**What have i done so far?**

- I am using a while loop to retrieve all the clients from the
  database. I have given each div that comes through a data-clientid
  for $_POST['ClientID'].
- I have classes called voteup and votedown so i can reference them in
  my JS script.
- In my script i assign the clientid from data-clientid to variables
  using the classes voteup and votedown
- In the voteup/down php files i then use this clientid to use the
  update sql to update the column.

**What is my code?**

**My main page that displays the clients and the voting buttons** *(Shortened to the bit you need to see, connection to the database is included and all of that works fine)*

```
<?php

$clientInfo = "SELECT * FROM Clients ORDER BY Client ASC";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $clientInfo);

echo "<div style='width: 100%; display: inline-block;'>";

while ($client = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<div class='clientid' style='height: 50px; font-size: 18px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 100%'>" . 

            "
            <div style='width: 35%;'></div>

            <div onclick=\"voteUp()\" style='display: inline-block; width: 5%;'>      
                <span style='font-size: 20px;' class='hover-cursor fa fa-chevron-up vote-up'></span>
            </div>" .

                 "<div class='hover-cursor hvr-underline-reveal voteup votedown' data-clientid='{$client['ClientID']}' style='width: 20%; display: inline-block;'>" . $client['Client'] . "</div>" . 

            "<div onclick=\"voteDown()\" style='display: inline-block; width: 5%;'>
                <span style='font-size: 20px; text-align: right;' class='hover-cursor fa fa-chevron-down vote-down'></span>
            </div>

            <div style='width: 35%;'></div>

         </div> 
        <br />";
}

echo "</div>";

?>
```

**This then links to my scripts file with my JQuery** *(I set it up to print the ID in the console so i can see which ID it is hitting. **Im just going to take Vote Up as an example**)*

```
window.voteUp = function() {
    var clientid = $(".voteup").data("clientid");

    $.post("voteup.php", {clientid: clientid}, function(data) {
       console.log("Data:" + clientid) 
    });
    return false;
}
```

**and then there is the voteup.php that i am referring to in my $.post**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['clientid'])) {
    $voteup = "UPDATE Clients SET Pos = (SELECT MAX(Pos) FROM Clients) + 1 WHERE ClientID = " . $_POST['clientid'];

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $voteup);
} else {
    echo "Failed";
}

?>
```

Comment: `$(".voteup").data("clientid")` will always return the `clientid` of the first element with class `voteup` (see [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)). Remove the inline JavaScript and use jQuery to [attach the event handlers](https://learn.jquery.com/events/).

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript issue**

As stated in comments, your Javascript code is getting only the first `voteup` element in the DOM Tree.

you need to use a dynamic way to find the specific `voteup` div for the client that you are voting up (or down), try this:

```
while ($client = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<div class='clientid' style='height: 50px; font-size: 18px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 100%'>" . 

            "
            <div style='width: 35%;'></div>

            <div style='display: inline-block; width: 5%;'>      
                <span style='font-size: 20px;' class='hover-cursor fa fa-chevron-up vote-up'></span>
            </div>" .

                 "<div class='hover-cursor hvr-underline-reveal voteup votedown' data-clientid='{$client['ClientID']}' style='width: 20%; display: inline-block;'>" . $client['Client'] . "</div>" . 

            "<div style='display: inline-block; width: 5%;'>
                <span style='font-size: 20px; text-align: right;' class='hover-cursor fa fa-chevron-down vote-down'></span>
            </div>

            <div style='width: 35%;'></div>

         </div> 
        <br />";
}
```

I've just removed the `onclick` event of your vote-up and vote-down buttons.

Now you need only one script:

```
<script>
    $(".vote-up").click(function(){
        var clientId = $(this).parents(".clientid").find(".voteup").data("clientid");

        $.post("voteup.php", {clientid: clientid}, function(data) {
            console.log("Data:" + clientid)
        });
        return false;
    });

    $(".vote-down").click(function(){
        var clientId = $(this).parents(".clientid").find(".votedown").data("clientid");

        $.post("votedown.php", {clientid: clientid}, function(data) {
            console.log("Data:" + clientid)
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Basically we are getting the top parent of vote-up button, the `div.clientid`, and with it, we search for the `div.voteup` that contains the `clientid data`

---

**PHP Issue**

Also, your UPDATE query is wrong, you are selecting the MAX(pox) from Clients through a subquery without the where clause, try this:

```
$voteup = "UPDATE Clients SET Pos = (SELECT MAX(Pos) FROM Clients WHERE ClientID = " . $_POST['clientid']. ") + 1 WHERE ClientID = " . $_POST['clientid'];
```

Later, try to transform your queries into parametrized queries, to avoid sql injection issues.

Comment: Hmm, this works, so its getting the differnent ID so thank you! however its taking the last Rating and adding plus 1, so say i have client a and client b, both are 0 rating, i vote up client A which now has 1 rating. when i vote up client B it gives them a rating of 2, whereas they should also be 1 because they were on 0 before

Comment: yep i jsut noticed that, i added in an extra where clause to the sub query in the 'select max'

Comment: ok, I've updated my answer too. You may want to accept the answer if it resolves your problem

Comment: Yep just sorted that, i shall accept your answer now, thank you for the help!